# Playwright JUnit report add name attribute to testsuites tag

Tags: junit, playwright, playwright-test

I am looking for a way to set the `name` attribute for the `<testsuites>` tag.

With the standard settings for the JUnit reporter, the `testsuites` tag looks like this:
`<testsuites id="" name="" tests=...>`

I would like to find a way to fill in the `name` attribute without writing a custom reporter.

I have already looked into the documentation for expanding the JUnit output. But as far as I found out, there is only the possibility to add new properties and not to fill attributes of existing properties.

edit:

In the `junit.js` file the attribute `name` is filled with the environment variable `PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_SUITE_NAME` after setting this in the console it works. But setting it in `test.beforeAll` before the test seems to be to late and is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an option in the configuration file for this, but this can be set through adding a `PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_SUITE_NAME` environment variable to your test command.

So if your test command is `yarn run test` you'd run `PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_SUITE_NAME=My\ Cool\ Test\ Suite yarn run test` instead.

[Defined in source code here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/aed86c98a8093bc18a1121f4b1263b64aa61c5de/packages/playwright/src/reporters/junit.ts#L75).

You can also pass `PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_SUITE_ID` to change the ID, if that's helpful to you.

Comment: Credit to @gorasa for this find of course. Since it lived in an edit I almost missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom reporter file CustomReporter.ts:

```
import { Reporter, TestCase } from '@playwright/test/reporter';

    class CustomReporter implements Reporter {
        // Add browser name to test suite junit report (it will not affect the HTML report)
        // this is needed to differentiate between same test file that run on different browsers in the junit
        onTestBegin(test: TestCase) {
            const browserName = `[${test.parent.parent!.title}]`
    
            // change test suite name (for junit): test-folder/example.spec.ts [firefox]
            test.parent.title = `${browserName} ${test.parent.title}`
    
            // change test case name: has title [firefox]
            // test.title += ` ${browserName}`
        }
    }
export default CustomReporter;
```

Now add it to the playwright.config.ts

```
reporter: [['./CustomReporter.ts'],
        ["html", {
            open: process.env.OPEN_REPORTER ? process.env.OPEN_REPORTER : 'always',
            outputFolder: "reports/playwright"
        }],
        ["junit", {
            outputFile: "reports/playwright/playwright-results.xml",
            outputFolder: "reports/playwright",
         }]];
```